# How can I *prevent* Apache2 from setting the Content-Type header?

Tags: apache, http, header, content-type

I have a CGI script that prints the following on stdout:

```
print "Status: 302 Redirect\n";
print "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1\n";
print "Location: $redirect\n";
print "Content-Length: 0\n";
print "Date: $date\n\n";
```

Where $redirect and $date are reasonable values. What Apache2 actually sends also includes a Content-Type: header (text/plain). I've commented out the DefaultType in the server configuration file.

I'm trying to debug a downstream problem that arises when no Content-Type: header is sent. So what magic incantation do I have to perform to *prevent* Apache2 from adding the content type header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my (admittedly brief) reading of server/protocol.c and server/core.c, you cannot.

It always defaults to DefaultType (text/plain by default) if that header is not present.

Comment: Ah. Grumble. I guess I'll have to setup some other web server in order to debug my client. (I'm trying to fix a bug report that says my code falls over if the server doesn't send a Content-Type at all.)

Comment: Will the CGI run on the command-line?  Just run the above script out of inetd perhaps?

Comment: Netcat is your friend.  Have it listen on a port and push back the content you want from a file.  No need to run it in inetd.

Answer (score 4):

Even if we delete the Content-Type header from the request via the "Header unset Content-Type" directive, apache regenerates the Content-Type header from another field of the request structure. Therefore, we first force that other field to a reserved value, in order to prevent the header regeneration, then we remove the Content-Type via the "Header unset" directive.

For apache2.2:

```
Header set Content-Type none
Header unset Content-Type
```

For apache2.4:

```
Header set Content-Type ""
Header unset Content-Type
```

Answer (score 1):

[RemoveType](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#removetype)  will stop sending a content type with the resource.

Addendum

```
<Files defaulttypenone.txt>
DefaultType None 
</Files>
<Files removetype.txt>
RemoveType .txt
</Files>
<Files forcetype.txt>
ForceType None
</Files>
```

Tested on my own server, these three solutions and none worked. They all returned text/plain.

Comment: <Files defaulttypenone.txt>
DefaultType None 
</Files>
<Files removetype.txt>
RemoveType .txt
</Files>
<Files forcetype.txt>
ForceType None
</Files>

Tested on my own server, this three solutions and none worked. They all returned text/plain.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are trying to do is prep a very specific test case server-side, you can always "cheat" by pre-baking output in a text file and having netcat listen for connections on some port.

I use that trick when I want to be 100% sure of each byte that the server sends.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the directive:

```
ResponseHeader unset Content-Type
```

Comment: No, although I can use header add to add new header (so I know header processing is being performed), header unset content-type has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

As I read [the Apache docs in question](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html), what you want may actually be

```
Header unset Content-Type
```

Hope this does it!

Comment: No, that didn't work. I think ResponseHeader became Header in Apache2.